# why my SpringBoot application loadLibrary .so UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, spring-boot, centos7, loadlibrary

I have a spring boot application with some initialization, but they rely on *.so，now I do `System.loadLibrary("cstaapi")` with `@Configuration`, when initializing, exception:

> 20180628 19:58:32,387 ERROR [main]
>   [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] Application startup
>   failed java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.xxx.module_init()V

I cannot find the reason?

---

The code:

```
@Configuration
public class LibLoader {
    static {
    System.out.println("==========LibLoader Configuration===========");
    System.loadLibrary("sntsapi");
    }
}


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableFeignClients
@ComponentScan(value = {"cn.xxx.*"})
@EntityScan("cn.xxx.*")
@EnableScheduling
public class CstaServiceApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("=== java.library.path ===" + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
    SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(CstaServiceApplication.class);
    springApplication.addListeners(new GlobalInit());
    springApplication.run(args);
}
}

public class GlobalInit implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> 
{
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent) {
        System.out.println("======== GlobalInit ========");
        GlobalInitManager.getInstance().doInit();
    }

}

@Configuration
public class LibLoader {
    static {
        System.out.println("==========LibLoader Configuration===========");
        System.loadLibrary("sntsapi");
    }
```

### }

The exception:

```
20180628 19:58:32,380  INFO [main] [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer]

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
20180628 19:58:32,387 ERROR [main] [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] Application startup failed
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.xxx.module_init()V
at com.xxx.apiJNI.module_init(Native Method) ~[csta.jar:?]
at com.xxx.apiJNI.<clinit>(sntsapiJNI.java:2039) ~[csta.jar:?]
at com.xxx.apiJNI.ACSHandle_t_4j.<init>(ACSHandle_t_4j.java:47) ~[csta.jar:?]
at cn.xxx.CstaSession.<init>(CstaSession.java:49) ~[CstaService.jar:?]
at cn.xxx.doInit(CstaSessionManager.java:49) ~[CstaService.jar:?]
at cn.xxx.doInit(GlobalInitManager.java:54) ~[CstaService.jar:?]
at cn.xxx.onApplicationEvent(GlobalInit.java:16) ~[CstaService.jar:?]
at cnxxx.onApplicationEvent(GlobalInit.java:10) ~[CstaService.jar:?]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:883) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at cn.xxx.CstaServiceApplication.main(CstaServiceApplication.java:34) [CstaService.jar:?]
20180628 19:58:32,394  INFO [main] [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext] Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@b12f8a: startup date [Thu Jun 28 19:58:28 CST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@15b810e
20180628 19:58:32,395  INFO [main] [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry] Unregistering application csta-service with eureka with status DOWN
```

Comment: Please post a complete stacktrace and not a very short extract of it.

Comment: I added.java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.xxx.module_init()V

Comment: Are you sure that your problem is related to Spring boot and not the JNI that you are using. Does it work with a simple main() application ?

Comment: I added LibLoader.java code with @Configuration, the syso print, I think it works.